# Select Overlaps dropdown menu

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, overlapping

Edit: Here's a fiddle with the situation:
http ://jsfiddle.net/ay9zT/

I come to you with a maybe simple question, but one that I haven't been able to solve.

I have a header menu which features a dropdown Menu and below it there's a Select, it works normally when it isn't selected, but when the Select is clicked on and you decide to hover to the header menu, the Select overlaps over the dropdown Menu, any idea why this happens? The Ul's Z-index is set to 1000, but it seems the Select ignores that. (The dropdown menu is actives when the mouse is hovering over it and not on-click).

Here's an example of the problem. Select overlapping the menu when selected and the dropdown showing, despite the Menu's z-index's value of 1000
https://i.stack.imgur.com/cg2DH.png

Comment: can you add a fiddle which replicates the issue?

Comment: Just found out what fiddle is, of course, right away, I'll edit it in the main post.

Comment: Added it, had some issues with the site not letting me post the link, so just remove the space between p and :